# Repl/ Xamarin UITest does not reflect state of an element when working with iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, read-eval-print-loop, xamarin.uitest

I have 3 elements (BoxView in Xamarin.Forms) that do have different background colors. My query, used to retrieve the color, against iOS simulator, is `...Invoke("backgroundColor").Invoke("styleString").Value<string>())[i]`. I do get the values for all 3 elements but they are all rgba(0,0,0,0.000). Visually the elements appear with the correct colors. Query against Android version of the application, also works fine `...Invoke("getBackground").Invoke("getColor").Value<int>())[i]`.
I wonder what do I do wrong? Is there another property that I should be querying for iOS?